# Using a ComboBox as ItemEditor in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemeditor

I have a simple DataGrid with data. Of one of the columns, I want to use a ComboBox to edit the field, instead of the standard edit box.

How do I do that? I have tried all kind of things I found on the internet, but they all fail in simply updating the value. I'd say it shouldn't be too hard to do this.

Comment: Show some code so we can figure out where you error is.  I've done this before w/o issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just wanted a simple drop down box, instead of a text-editing field.

The following code does want I want:

```
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="type" headerText="Type" editorDataField="value">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:ComboBox>
                        <mx:dataProvider>
                            <fx:String>Gauge</fx:String>
                            <fx:String>Graph</fx:String>
                            <fx:String>Indicator</fx:String>
                        </mx:dataProvider>
                    </mx:ComboBox>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in the process of doing this myself, and with the spark:DataGrid it actually gets a bit easier than halo - but both follow the same setup / architecture.

Start with:

```
spark.components.gridClasses.ComboBoxGridItemEditor;
```

Depending on the nature of your data setup and/or how prolific this kind of editing will be for your application, you can write it inline as most documentation will suggest within a <fx:component>, or simply subclass this (although behind the scenes these are the same thing - the later being much easier to reuse). The data for the combo in my scenario is a sub selection of a bigger parent object, so I chose to make it easier on myself and add an additional property **dataField** to mimic other renderer / editors - in what actually shows in just the cell itself (when not in editing mode).

A basic setup looks something more or less like this (at least mine does):

```
public class AccountComboEditor extends ComboBoxGridItemEditor
{
     private _dataField:String;

     public function AccountComboEditor()
     {
         super();
         //note - typically you wouldn't do "logic" in the view but it's simplified as an example
         addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);
     }

     public function get dataField():String { return _dataField; }

     public function set dataField(value:String):void
     {
         if (_dataField !=value) //dosomeadditionalvalidation();
         _dataField = value;
     }


     override public function prepare():void
     {
        super.prepare();

        if (data && dataField && comboBox) comboBox.labelField = data[dataField];
     }

     protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
     {
         //now setup the dataProvider to your combo box - 
         //as a simple example mine comse out of a model

         dataProvider = model.getCollection();
         //this isn't done yet though - now you need a listener on the combo to know
         //what item was selected, and then get that data_item (label) back onto this 
         //editor so it has something to show when the combo itself isn't in
         //editor mode
     }
}
```

So the real take away is to setup the **labelField** of the combobox, either internally in the subclass or externally if you need to expose it as an additional property.

The next part is to use this as part of the **mx.core.ClassFactory** for the actual data grid. A simple view would look like something similar:

```
<s:DataGrid>
   <fx:Script>
        private function getMyEditor(dataField:String):ClassFactory
        {
           var cf:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(AccountComboEditor);
               cf.properties = {dataField : dataField };
           return cf;
        }
   </fx:Script>

   <s:columns>
      <mx:ArrayList>
         <s:GridColumn itemEditor="{getMyEditor('some_data_property')}" />
      </mx:ArrayList>
   </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

This [Creating item renderers...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.5/UsingSDK/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc364-1a0b75ef12ddd639592-8000.html) doc will give you more info.